# pgloader cannot import while using TARGET COLUMNS

Tags: postgresql, pgloader

I am having a hard time getting pgloader to work while trying to use the `TARGET COLUMNS` optional arguments.

```
LOAD CSV
            FROM INLINE
                    HAVING FIELDS
                    (
                            npi,
                            ...
                     )
             INTO postgresql://user:pass!n@pg2/nadb?tablename=tempload
                    (
                            npi
                    )
            WITH    skip header = 1,
                    fields optionally enclosed by '"',
                    fields escaped by double-quote,
                    fields terminated by ','

            SET     work_mem to '64MB'

    BEFORE LOAD EXECUTE
            tempload.sql;
```

If I don't use the target columns then it works just fine.  `tempload` has the exact same columns as `data.csv`.

Everytime i run it it hangs up at this point:

```
2016-06-09T17:17:33.749000-05:00 DEBUG
select i.relname,
       n.nspname,
       indrelid::regclass,
       indrelid,
       indisprimary,
       indisunique,
       pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid),
       c.conname,
       pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid)
  from pg_index x
       join pg_class i ON i.oid = x.indexrelid
       join pg_namespace n ON n.oid = i.relnamespace
       left join pg_constraint c ON c.conindid = i.oid
 where indrelid = 'tempload'::regclass
```

I'm at a total loss.  Like I said, it works fine if I don't use `TARGET COLUMNS`, so I really don't believe it is the data.

I get the same thing with release `3.2` and the docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue has to do with the amount of memory.  I changed to `SET work_mem = '512'` and it started to get past that point.  I guess this has to do with the face that I have 330 columns to import.